# how to select only filtered rows using selectall javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a script for filter text box on gridview and script for check boxes on each row.
When i filter something in grid i will get some filtered rows.. i want to select those filtered rows using selectall script. but it is selecting all results in grid.

select checkbox script:

```
      $("#<%=gvCheckDetails.ClientID%> input:checkbox").live("click", function(event) {
            var tbl = $("#<%=gvCheckDetails.ClientID%>");
            var checkbox = $(this);
            var checkState = checkbox.is(":checked");
            var ancestorName = checkbox.parent().parent()[0].nodeName; // tr or th?                

            // if it's a header, we'll work with all rows (select on or off)
            if (ancestorName.toLowerCase() === "th") {
                $(tbl[0].config.rowsCopy).each(function() {
                    if (checkState)
                        $(this).find("input:checkbox").attr('checked', true);
                    else
                        $(this).find("input:checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
                });
            }
        });
```

Can any one help me how can i modifiy above script to select only filtered values when selectall checked (search textbox is dynamically filtering grid rows using jscript in aspx)

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of this please?

Comment: So you use select All to select rows that are already filtered from select All? That make me a bit queasy.

Comment: Problem solved now.. posted answer below. Thanks for quick the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved based on [Augusto Men](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317971/augusto-men) Answer:**

just replaced

```
$(this).find("input:checkbox").attr('checked', true);
```

with

```
$(this).filter(':visible').find("input:checkbox").attr('checked', true);
```

so now checkbox check is filtering and applying only visable ones.

Thanks you so much **Augusto**

Answer (score 0):

The `:visible` selector will usually do the trick. It will filter only the elements that are visible, including its parents in the DOM.

```
$(tbl[0].config.rowsCopy).filter(':visible').each(function() {
```

Comment: Thanks Augusto, Its looks like the solution but not working. When i click selectall checkbox nothing is happening... probably we need to change something or somewhere in the code. Can you plz modify it to work properly...

Comment: Can you check whether `$(tbl[0].config.rowsCopy).filter(':visible')` returns something (i.e., what you were excepting - the visible rows)?

Comment: Finally problem solved by adding filter $(this).filter(':visible').find("input:checkbox").attr('checked', true);